# Create a link with JSON and PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP file which renders out a JSON call and I'm trying to wrap the links into the titles using PHP.

```
<?php
$jsondata = file_get_contents("https://app.citizenspace.com/api/2.3/json_consultation_details?    dept=parliament&id=ddcengage&fields=all");

$json = json_decode($jsondata,true);
$output = "<ul>";
foreach($json['related_links'] as $relatedlinks) {
$output .= "<li>".$relatedlinks['title']."</li>";
$output .= "<h4>".$relatedlinks['url']."</h4>";

}

$output .= "</ul>";
echo $output;
?>
```

What do I need to do to create the Title as the URL?

Comment: ignore the php... you're building HTML... how do you make a link in HTML? That'll tell you what you need to do with the PHP code.

Comment: tried this 

<?php
$jsondata = file_get_contents ("https://app.citizenspace.com/api/2.3/json_consultation_details?dept=parliament&id=ddcengage&fields=all");

$json = json_decode($jsondata,true);
$output = "<ul>";
foreach($json['related_links'] as $relatedlinks) {

$output .= "<li>"

<a href=".$relatedlinks['url']">
.$relatedlinks['title']
</a>

."</li>";



}

$output .= "</ul>";
echo $output;

?>

No joy though

Comment: Pleaee [edit] your question to include referenced code. No one will see code buried in comments, and it's very hard to read besides.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like the below code:

`$output .= "<li><a href=".$relatedlinks['url'].">".$relatedlinks['title']."</a></li>";`

?

Comment: I have tried a similar approach to render the 'View' URL from the JSON response which is tho, but this doesn't seem to work though.


<div style="float:left;border:10px solid #f5f5f5;width:40%;">
<?php


$jsondata = file_get_contents ("https://app.citizenspace.com/api/2.3/json_consultation_details?dept=parliament&id=ddcengage&fields=all");
$json = json_decode($jsondata,true);


<a href="

echo $json['url'];

">view</a>

?>

</div>

Comment: I'm glad that I could help :)
Could you accept my answer though ? Thank's !

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need

```
<div style="float:left;border:10px solid #f5f5f5;width:40%;"> 
<?php 
$jsondata = file_get_contents ("https://app.citizenspace.com/api/2.3/json_consultation_details?dept=parliament&id=ddcengage&fields=all%22"); 
$json = json_decode($jsondata,true); 
echo "<a href=".$json['url'].">".$json['title']."</a>";
?> 
</div>
```

Since you dont have a json array, remove the loop!